# add target='_top" to php header location

Tags: php

I am using some new software that includes a login php setup. Works fine until I decided to open the login page in a lightbox. Now I can't break out of the light box to a normal view browser page for my success destination page. The php code is as follows;

```
    <?php
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' && isset($_POST['form_name'])     && $_POST['form_name'] == 'loginform')
{
   $success_page = './club_registered_breeders_only.php';
   $error_page = './Error_form_failure.html';
   $database = './usersdb.php';
   $crypt_pass = md5($_POST['password']);
   $found = false;
   $fullname = '';
   $session_timeout = 600;
   if(filesize($database) > 0)
   {
      $items = file($database, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);
      foreach($items as $line)
      {
         list($username, $password, $email, $name, $active) = explode('|', trim($line));
         if ($username == $_POST['username'] && $active != "0" && $password == $crypt_pass)
         {
            $found = true;
            $fullname = $name;
         }
      }
   }
   if($found == false)
   {
      header('Location: '.$error_page);
      exit;
   }
   else
   {
      if (session_id() == "")
      {
         session_start();
      }
      $_SESSION['username'] = $_POST['username'];
      $_SESSION['fullname'] = $fullname;
      $_SESSION['expires_by'] = time() + $session_timeout;
      $_SESSION['expires_timeout'] = $session_timeout;
      $rememberme = isset($_POST['rememberme']) ? true : false;
      if ($rememberme)
      {
         setcookie('username', $_POST['username'], time() + 3600*24*30);
         setcookie('password', $_POST['password'], time() + 3600*24*30);
      }
      header('Location: '.$success_page);
      exit;
   }
}
$username = isset($_COOKIE['username']) ? $_COOKIE['username'] : '';
$password = isset($_COOKIE['password']) ? $_COOKIE['password'] : '';
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' && isset($_POST['form_name']) && $_POST['form_name'] == 'forgotpasswordform')
{
   $email = isset($_POST['email']) ? addslashes($_POST['email']) : '';
   $found = false;
   $items = array();
   $success_page = '';
   $error_page = './Error_form_failure.html';
   $database = './usersdb.php';
   if (filesize($database) == 0 || empty($email))
   {
      header('Location: '.$error_page);
      exit;
   }
   else
   {
      $items = file($database, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);
      foreach($items as $line)
      {
         list($username, $password, $emailaddress, $fullname, $active) = explode('|', trim($line));
         if ($email == $emailaddress && $active != "0")
         {
            $found = true;
         }
      }
   }
   if ($found == true)
   {
      $alphanum = array('a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','x','y','z','A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','M','N','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9');
      $chars = sizeof($alphanum);
      $a = time();
      mt_srand($a);
      for ($i=0; $i < 6; $i++)
      {
         $randnum = intval(mt_rand(0,55));
         $newpassword .= $alphanum[$randnum];
      }
      $crypt_pass = md5($newpassword);
      $file = fopen($database, 'w');
      foreach($items as $line)
      {
         $values = explode('|', trim($line));
         if ($email == $values[2])
         {
            $values[1] = $crypt_pass;
            $line = '';
            for ($i=0; $i < count($values); $i++)
            {
               if ($i != 0)
                  $line .= '|';
               $line .= $values[$i];
            }
         }
         fwrite($file, $line);
         fwrite($file, "\r\n");
      }
      fclose($file);
      $mailto = $_POST['email'];
      $subject = 'New password';
      $message = 'Your new password for Club Login is:';
      $message .= $newpassword;
      $header  = "From: webmaster@whiteshepherdsnz.com"."\r\n";
      $header .= "Reply-To: webmaster@whiteshepherdsnz.com"."\r\n";
      $header .= "MIME-Version: 1.0"."\r\n";
      $header .= "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8"."\r\n";
      $header .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit"."\r\n";
      $header .= "X-Mailer: PHP v".phpversion();
      mail($mailto, $subject, $message, $header);
      header('Location: '.$success_page);
   }
   else
   {
      header('Location: '.$error_page);
   }
   exit;
}
?>
```

Somehow I need to set target="-top" so the success page opens in the same window with normal browser view. Can someone show me how to achieve this please. I have no skills in this stuff just what I pick up from reading these sites and applying to my problem
Thanks
Roger

Comment: Is the light box using an iframe?

Comment: Basically, if what you're saying is that your redirect is redirecting inside something, instead of redirecting the page, there is nothing PHP can do. You need to do something about it on the browser side.

Answer (score 2):

To keep it short and clear, you will need the `#` in your url.

```
header("Location: index.php#top");
```

That will redirect you to `index.php` and set the target to `#top`

Note: Remember that `header('Location: ...')` should redirect to an url like you would use in your browser. Not the internal server path.

Comment: target="_TOP" in an anchor tag (which I think is what OP is saying he wants to happen via PHP), isn't the same as just targeting the top of a page.

Answer (score 1):

Try with Window-target

```
header('Window-target: _top');
header('Location: index.php');
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately WYSIWYG Web Builder only allows the selection of an internal page address and will not allow edit so unable to try that out. However another solution was found using Java script in the head of the destination page:

```
    <script>
this.top.location !== this.location && (this.top.location = this.location);
</script>
```

this worked perfectly. I will pass your comments on to the WYSIWYG Web Builder Forum.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If Your Doing a form way
you can put a target in the form like this.

```
<form action="" method="" target="_top">
<input type="" name="">
</form>
```